# Is it possible to show staggered layout in pure list view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, nativescript, radlistview

I want to make collapsible custom action bar. So I used RadListView with staggered layout. then with the help of its scroll events as below.

```
let lastOffset;

exports.onScrollStarted = function (args) {
    lastOffset = args.object.getScrollOffset();
}

exports.onScrollDragEnded = function (args) {
    let currentOffset = args.object.getScrollOffset();
    let direction = currentOffset < lastOffset ? "up" : "down";
    var scroll_difference = currentOffset - lastOffset
    console.log(scroll_difference);

    if (scroll_difference >= 5 || scroll_difference <= -5) {

        console.log(direction)
        if (direction == "down") {
            wrap_animate.actionbar_hide(id_action_bar, id_content);
            wrap_animate.shrink_view(id_bottom, id_selornt_logo);
        } else if (direction == "up") {
            wrap_animate.actionbar_show(id_action_bar, id_content);
            wrap_animate.expand_view(id_bottom, id_selornt_logo);
        }

        lastOffset = currentOffset;
    }
}
```

I achieved the collapsible view. but it will not work properly when I test it rigorously, i.e. when I scroll down and up without giving time.sometimes action bar will not hide or show properly. But it will work fine with normal list view as it supports scroll gesture event which gives top, down, left and right swipe event. But how to put staggered gird layout in normal list view. If that is possible then I can go for list view only as it fits all my requirement. except staggered gird layout which is common in all on line shopping apps. I want to want list view supports staggered list or not. and is there any better way to achieve this.

Comment: ListView doesn't do any fancy, only RadListView does with all different layouts, selections, drag reorder etc., If you face issues with hiding / showing ActionBar, please share a Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @Manoj  thank you for the feeback. i have created a plaground sample below. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=jK5Mdg&v=2    ,in order to reproduce the issue. scrolldown scrollup without giving time for page to rest. then it is noticed that action bar will not visible even if it is scrolling up.                  if scrolled slowly it works fine but on pull to refresh it is giving actionbar visiblility problem i.e it is not visible only in fast  mode of scrolling.

Comment: @Manoj please do give some suggestions on better ways to achieve this smooth animation.

Comment: It only fails when this condition in your code is not satisfied, `if (scroll_difference >= 5 || scroll_difference <= -5) {`, I'm not sure why you have this, it necessarily need not to be 5 points all the time. Otherwise it seems to work on my end.

Comment: @Manoj i forgot to mention, when pulltorefresh swiped then action bar will go off if i dont provide scroll_difference.

Comment: @Manoj in order to animate action bar even when drag event is still on go i put that. i think if you scroll up and down little fast then you will find the problem. because the app i'm going to do will be used by users for data entry purpose so they are little fast when using the app so they are facing problem. for reference i have done the same thing in listview below. kindly have a look at the below link play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=jK5Mdg&v=3 you will notice the difference. also if there are any other best way to do this kindly tell me the procedure, i ll try..